# Yii2 How to get common/web/fileuploads/image.jpg from backend/view/department/view.php

Tags: php, html, yii2

```
<?php  $dir=Yii::getAlias("@common/web/fileuploads/"); ?>
<img src="<?=$dir. $model->file_id ?>" width="200" height='200' />
```

please help me how to get image from backend/view .i need to go up the directory from view folder.Thank You!

Comment: You haven't specified what are you strong in `file_id`. Is it the full path or just the file name, i.e. image.jpg. Also, what's the error are you getting in console, e.g. image/path/url not found or something else?

Comment: file_id is just a name and no error but image not show in webpage. common and backend are same directory level.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get baseUrl of your app.

```
<?= Html::img(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/../../common/web/fileuploads/'.$model->file_id ,['width' => 200 ,'height' => 200])?>
```

Comment: <img src="/backendERegi/common/web/fileuploads/Chrysanthemum.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt=""> i see that in inspect element in browser but image not show

Comment: have you changed your directory structure of backend ..in which folder your entry script reside.

Comment: When I create a project, I set WAMP apache alias to backend\web. Is that the reason that I can go up above alias directory. Is that good to set apache directory there?

Comment: ok ...image is showing in console..but not displaying on document means you have to refresh your dom element ..

Comment: i don't know how to refresh dom

Answer (score 1):

you just add **backend->config->main.php**

```
   return [
      'components' => [
          'urlManager' => [
              // here is your backend URL rules
          ],
          'urlManagerCommon' => [
             'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
             'baseUrl' => 'common/wb/', //access common web url in backend
             'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
             'showScriptName' => false,
          ],
      ],
  ];
```

and then access the web in `backend` like

```
<?=  Html::img(Yii::$app->urlManagerCommon->baseUrl.'/fileuploads/'.$model->file_id, ['width' => 200 ,'height' => 200, 'alt' => 'No Image']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your config file, declare the *alias*:

```
'aliases' => [
        '@files' => '@common/web/fileuploads/',
         [...]
```

And then, you could access with:

```
<img src="<?= Yii::getAlias('@files') . $model->file_id ?>" />
```

Check Firebug if the image doesn't show, to see what's the problem in the path.

Comment: <img src="D:\Phoenix\project\Project-eRegi\eregi\common/web/fileuploads/Chrysanthemum.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt=""> 
directory is that but image not show

Comment: How did you set your project? I mean, the images should be in the root directory, usually in frontend/web, to be accessible

Comment: I want it to be accessible from both frontend and backend. So, I saved it to the common folder. I could save it from backend/controller/. But I can't get it back from backend/view

Comment: But the base URL has to be the same for both, if you save it in @frontend/web you could access by your domain/imagePath and with @webroot to upload / delete

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the web folder in your URL is the default public Yii folder, you should be able to view the image as shown below.

```
Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web') . '/fileuploads/' . $model->file_id ,['width' => 200 ,'height' => 200])
```

But if you have changed the folder structure then share the complete path of the folder where your images are saved.

Comment: my image are saved in common/web/fileuploads

Comment: Need the complete path. Also, the above code isn't working?

Comment: yeap code isn't working 
D:\Projecti\phoenix\common\web\fileuploads

Comment: Can you share the URL which is being generated (not working) using the code I shared in the answer.

Comment: your code directory is goto backend/web/fileuploads